# flyspell: ignore certain words in a buffer, but not others?

Tags: flyspell, file-local-variables, spell-checking

There are some words I want flyspell to ignore in some buffers, but not others.

For example, in one buffer I want `etaoin` to *not* be flagged by flyspell because in that context it's not a misspelling (because, say, I'm talking about [typesetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etaoin_shrdlu)) -- but in other buffers, that should be considered a misspelled word.

It seems like there could be some way to do this with file-local variables? Something like

```
# Local Variables:
# flyspell-ignore-words: ("etaoin" "shrdlu")
# End:
```

so that in that buffer, `etaoin` and `shrdlu` would be considered correct, but incorrect elsewhere (if they're not in your dictionary, of course).

Suggestions?

Comment: Try placing something like this at the bottom of the file -- do not use the Local Variables format for this particular purpose:  `LocalWords:  foo bar baz`  In addition, you may wish to investigate the variable `ispell-buffer-session-localwords` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't directly convert @lawlist's comment into an answer, but it's exactly what I wanted: `ispell.el` has

```
(defconst ispell-words-keyword "LocalWords: "
  "The keyword for local oddly-spelled words to accept.
The keyword will be followed by any number of local word spellings.
There can be multiple instances of this keyword in the file.")
```

For my particular question, you would do

```
LocalWords: etaoin shrdlu
```

It seems like, if you really want to use file-local variables, one should be able to also set `ispell-buffer-session-localwords` to the corresponding list, but I haven't been able to get the quoting and such to work. But since the above is simple and does precisely what I want, there seems to be no need.

(Amusingly, "localwords" gets flagged as misspelled when you add it.)

Answer (score 0):

Flyspell relies on an external spell–checker called Ispell (although your OS may come with a substitute such as Aspell instead). It provides no means of ignoring specific words, either on a buffer–local basis or otherwise.

You can choose a different dictionary for a buffer by setting `ispell-local-dictionary`. You can do so as a file or directory variable.